# Do I need to define the exact same structure of a JSON to use it with json.Unmarshal?

Tags: json, go

I'm fetching a subreddit and receiving it as a JSON response.

The problem is that the return is kinda big, with lots of fields, but I just want some of them.

The structure is something like:

`data.children.data.fields`

Children is an array, so I can't access it like that I suppose, but this is just an example.

I pasted the JSON on QuickType to see what it returns me, the structs are big.

[Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io?share=9RfYqpeMAd0jTlwi8jZy)

So, is there a way I can get only the fields I want to using json.Unmarshal?

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can define a struct whose structure matches that of the fields you want, you don't have to define all fields just because they are in the json, define only those that you need, just make sure they match in structure and type.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try that

Comment: I did not know about Quicktype - that is too cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a struct with fields that you only want. Look at the example below

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    Field1 int    `json:"field1"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2"`
}

func main() {

    jsonString := `{
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": "test field 2",
    "field3": "test field 3"
}`

    t := Test{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &t)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("\n", t)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qFLXBiU-fMX